# How to use percentage weights with math.random

Tags: java, math, random, percentage

Working on a homework assignment, honestly not even sure how to go about doing this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Assignment:
A drunken person leaves a bar and heads home walking. It is observed that on average he steps forward 60% of the time, steps backward 30% of the time, and wobbles (no forward or backward movements) 10% of the time.

His home is 50 feet (steps) from the bar. Write a Program called “PS1P2” that displays his movements on a typical night when he is walking home drunk. Your code should print a series of “Forward”, “Backward”, and “Wobble” words
corresponding to his movements.

Hint: You may use value generated by Math.random() to determine the person’s action
in each step.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double currentPos = 0;
    int houseDist = 50;
    int stepCounter = 0;
    double i;

    while(currentPos < houseDist){
        i = Math.random();
        if(i <= 0.6){
            System.out.println("Forward");
            currentPos++;
            stepCounter++;
        }
        if(i <= 0.9){
            System.out.println("Backward");
            currentPos--;
            stepCounter++;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Wobble");
    }
    System.out.println("Total steps: " + stepCounter);
    System.out.println("The house has been reached!");



}//end main
```

Got it figured out! Didn't want this to seem like you guys were doing my homework for me, just needed somewhere to start. Thanks to those who did answer/help!

Comment: You really need to show some attempt at answering yourself otherwise this comes across as a "show me teh codez!" question.  Have you got any working code at all?

Comment: Hint: The result of [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) is in the range [0,1). If the results of `Math.random()` are evenly distributed, the probability that the result will be in the range [0,0.1) is …?

Comment: In your posted code, you don't need to check `i > 0.6` if you use `else if`.

Comment: @Pancakes It won't work right without the `else` before the second `if`:  `else if (i <= 0.9)`.  You **don't** want to enter the second `if` clause if you have gone through the first one, which is what `else` is for.

Answer (score 3):

Math.random isn't going to solve this problem for you automagically...

In software engineering, there is typically a planning phase before coding starts. So let's plan!

I would recommend you think about this problem on paper. Pretend you had, like, a 100-sided dice, and you were going to roll it over and over, and use the value to figure out what the guy did, right? I'd recommend figuring out how you would do this, and writing it out on paper first. Figure it out step by step (no pun intended)

Then, once you've done that, realize that invoking Math.random is basically like rolling the dice (without looking up the code, I believe invoking Math.random(100) returns a random number between 1-100, or something like that. JavaDoc/Google will be able to help you with how to invoke it properly). The rest is up to you to code.

Comment: I'll let OP figure that out on his own ;)

Comment: Math.random() doesn't accept an argument, it returns between 0.0 and 1.0.  You're thinking of Random.nextInt(100) which will give you a value between 0 and 99 (the value you provide is exclusive)

Comment: Nice answer! For the sake of completeness: There is only [`Math.random()`](docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) which returns a `double` in the range [0,1), no `Math.random(int)`.

Comment: I believe you can use Math.number(Math.random()*100) to get numbers between 1-100. I'm planning on using a while loop and associating number ranges with the probabilities of each (forward, backward, wobble) instance that can happen.

Comment: @Pancakes Sounds like a plan. If you found my question helpful, I'd appreciate an upvote or a green checkmark ;)